# Using a BitBucket Repository Locally with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

My company has just begun using BitBucket with Mercurial for version control and I am having a heck of a time integrating it locally with Visual Studio 2010. I can easily create a folder on my local system and clone the BitBucket repository using TortoiseHg and it brings down all the files appropriately. However, when I try to create a Visual Studio project in the same folder, it insists on creating it's own sub-folder for the project files, leaving my version controlled source files out of the project. When I try to do it the opposite way, creating my solution in Visual Studio first, TortoiseHg will not let me clone my repository into the same directory, saying that it needs a new folder. All of my google-foo seems to be coming up fruitless.

Anyone have a clean way of setting up a cloned repository from which to work locally in Visual Studio using Mercurial and BitBucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

1. Create your Visual Studio project.
2. Right-click the project folder and choose *TortoiseHg* -> *Create Repostory Here*.
3. Add and commit files in TortoiseHg.
4. Push the repository into a new **empty** repository on Bitbucket. To push, you use the synchronize view and add a new path to the repository. Name the path `default` and it will become the default push and pull path.

The important point is that you can always push into an empty repository. This is how you copy a repository you've worked on locally to Bitbucket: create a new empty repository online and push to it.

Comment: The problem with this is that the repositories are already created on Bitbucket. I need those files in my project as well as in the repository.

Comment: Hmm, if you really cannot make VS create the project at the top-level in your clone, then you can move the files in your clone. So create the project where you want it and clone the repo somewhere else. Then move the `.hg` folder and all the other files and folders in the repo into the project folder. You'll see that `hg status` or TortoiseHg status lists the VS project files as unknown — that's okay since you want to add and commit them.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I just assumed that the repository had to stay where I created it originally. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Right, that's a common assumption. But Mercurial repositories don't really know where they are on disk! So you can move them around like you want.

Comment: Ok, the trouble I'm having now is that the Visual Studio project doesn't see the files that I have added to the directory and I can't find a way to add the folder to it.

Comment: Ok, I got that one to work! I didn't realize I could drag and drop folders from windows explorer into my project. All set!